# Google フォームでドメイン内の回答者のメールアドレスをgoolge スクリプトから参照したい

Tags: google-apps-script

Google フォームでドメイン内のアンケートを作成しています。
現在、回答者のメールアドレスは手入力してもらっているのですが、
これを自動にしてほしいという要望がきています。

もう少し具体的にいうとフォーム送信時のトリガーで
回答者のメールアドレスをgoogle スクリプト参照できるようにしたいです。

回答者に手入力してもらわずにgoogle スクリプトで回答者のメールアドレスを
取得することは可能でしょうか。

Comment: できれば、作られたgoogleスクリプトを質問に追加して頂けませんか？　実際のスクリプトのコードがあると、回答が具体的になると思いますので。

Answer (score 1):

「フォーム送信時のトリガーで回答者のメールアドレス」というのは現在ログイン中のユーザーということでよいでしょうか？
以下のような形で取得可能かと思います。

```
 var usr = Session.getActiveUser();
 var email = usr.getEmail();
```

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session

Comment: すいません。上手くいかないです。
Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()は回答者のメールアドレスではなく、フォーム作成者のメールアドレスが帰ってきているように見えます。

Comment: 別のアカウントでログインしても作成者のメールアドレスが帰ってきますか。